# Haskell - span elem: evaluation

Tags: haskell, evaluation

I would like to know how haskell evauates the following expression.

```
span (`elem` ['A'..'Z']) "BOBsidneyMORGANeddy"
```

The result is

```
("BOB","sidneyMORGANeddy")
```

Could anyone explain me the evaluation process? Because I can't tell why it is split as above.

Comment: It's split at `s` because that is the first letter that is _not_ in the set `'A'..'Z'`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`span` will partition the list into two using a predicate in such a way that the first part is the longest prefix for which a given predicate holds true, and the second part is the remainder of the list. In other words, the first part is obtained like with `takeWhile`, and the second part is obtained like with `dropWhile` for the same predicate.

Now let's look at the predicate. `elem :: a->[a]->Bool` tells whether the given element is found in the given list. The neat trick is that any function of two or more arguments can be used in infix notation:

```
x `elem` xs
```

is the same as `elem x xs`. Therefore,

```
`elem` xs
```

is treated just like sections of infix functions. It is the same as `\x -> elem x xs`.

You can see now that `span` is given a predicate testing whether the elements of the list to split can be found in the list `['A'..'Z']`. So it will split the list into two: it finds the first element for which the predicate doesn't hold, and that's the split point. This is how the second partition starts with the first lowercase letter.